# How can I find a game in Steam that has had a trial period in the past?

Tags: steam

A while back I played an awesome Steam game. The game normally costs around $20 but there was a free trial period/weekend at the time, so I played it for a little. Now a year later I really want to buy the game because I have the money and a better Mac and such, but I can't find it.

Is there anyway I can find it through Steam (using filters or a specialized search or something)?

Comment: Voting to close as a recommendation. While it's not quite looking for a recommendation, you're asking us to find a game without even providing the name of it.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf No, it's not a game recommendation question. He's asking if there's a way, in Steam, to see games that have had this type of trial period in the past.

Comment: @MageXy That's reaching a bit, I don't see a lot of context to put it that way.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Quote from the question: "Is there anyway I can find [this game]?". He's not asking us what game it is, he's asking how he can help himself find it. Interpreting that as "how can I find games in Steam that have had a trial period in the past" isn't that much of a stretch. At the very least, my interpretation would make this question on-topic, even if (as I suspect) the answer is "no", and we should always be trying to improve questions to stay on-topic if possible.

Comment: If the OP wants to clarify what exactly he wants, then it might be a different story.

Comment: @MageXy I agree.

Comment: @OP I have edited your question to be a little more clear. If my edit is not what you're actually looking for, please update your question to clarify.

Comment: You might be able to find a tool like http://www.lorenzostanco.com/lab/steam/ to list all the games you have played and compare it to the games that you have in your library. The game might still be in your steam folder. I can't really answer it, because I can't test any of my theories, since I have never actually played a game on a f2p weekend only.

Answer (score 3):

According to [steam](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/10/364041517008298297/), downloaded 'free weekend games' are not removed from your local hard drive, unless you manually remove them. The games name also remains in your library, unless you manually remove it. So you could find it that way.

If you did manually uninstall it and remove it, another possible way to figure out what the game was is to go through your [user history](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1316177), though I can't find a reliable source to verify if free games show up in that history or not.